# How to get keystroke

Tags: vb.net

I want to go get keystrokes, and this code works. But when I add a button or textbox the code is not running. Can any one help me with this code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) > 1 Then Label1.Text = e.KeyChar
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Think you might want to look at the KeyPreview property of the form (if memory serves me correct)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Form's `KeyPreview` property to `True`, in which case the Form will raise those keyboard events

[image]